# NextAuth Credential redirect error with no clues logs in console

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13, next-auth

I am trying to use `NextAuth Credentials` in my NextJs app. However, after user signs into the app with the correct credentials, nothing happens.

The expected behavior is to redirect user to the dashboard after successful authentication, but nothing happens, no log in the `console`, no log in the `Network` tab or anything that provides clue. Please help debug this. Thanks.

Below are copies of my code from the responsible files:

`/[...nextauth].js`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from '../../../utils/db';
import { compare } from "bcrypt";

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "you@company.com" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                let existingUser = null;

                try {
                    if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
                        throw new Error("Missing credentials");
                    }

                    existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                        where: {
                            email: credentials?.email
                        },
                    });

                    if (!existingUser) {
                        throw new Error("User not found");
                    }

                    const passwordMatch = await compare(credentials?.password, existingUser.password);

                    if (!passwordMatch) {
                        throw new Error("Invalid password");
                    }

                    return {
                        id: `${existingUser.id}`,
                        email: existingUser.email
                    };
                } catch (error) {
                    // Log the error or handle it appropriately
                    console.error("Authentication error:", error.message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }),
    ],
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
        signOut: '/login',
        error: '/404',
        dashboard: '/dashboard',
    },
    debug: true,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

`/signIn.js`

```
//SignIn
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Loading from './Loading';
import PasswordReset from './PassReset';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const SignIn = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    const router = useRouter();


    const handleOnSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            console.log("Attempting to sign in with:", email, password);

            const signInData = await signIn('Credentials', {
                email,
                password,
                // redirect: false,
            });

            console.log("signInData:", signInData);

            if (signInData.ok & session) {
                console.log("Sign-in successful!");
                router.push('/dashboard');
            } else {
                console.error('Authentication failed:', signInData.error);
                setErrors(`Authentication failed: ${signInData.error}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Authentication error:', error.message);
            setErrors(`Authentication error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    };

    const setErrors = (error) => {
        return error.message
    };

    const openModal = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setOpen(true);
    };

    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className="">
                <>
                    <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} className="">
                        <label htmlFor="email" >
                            Email address
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            label="Email address"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                            required
                           
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="password">
                            Password
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            label="Password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                            required
        
                        />
                    </form>
                </>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

`prisma`

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { withAccelerate } from "@prisma/extension-accelerate";

let prisma: PrismaClient;

const globalForPrisma = global as any;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  // In development, use a global singleton to avoid multiple instances in hot-reloading
  if (!globalForPrisma.prisma) {
    globalForPrisma.prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends(withAccelerate());
  }
  prisma = globalForPrisma.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```